# Git Push / Git clone não funciona mesmo após settar uma chave SSH corretamente

Tags: git, gitlab

Mesmo settando corretamente uma chave SSH do tipo RSA, assim como descrito em: 
[GIT LAB SSH](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html), fiz diversos testes e adicionei um arquivo `config:`

```
Host gitlab.com
    Hostname gitlab.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
```

Tenho dentro da pasta `.SSH:`

```
config  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Já testei diversas soluções, mas para qualquer comando de acesso externo eu recebo como resposta o erro:

```
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Você colocou na sua conta do gitlab essa chave específica?

Comment: Coloquei, inclusive chequei para ver se estava correto, e fiz duas vezes a criação e nada adiantou.

Comment: Nessa linha do `config` ==> `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab`, você está ensinando ao `ssh` que a sua identidade para o gitlab é o arquivo `gitlab` dentro da pasta `.ssh`. Eu nunca tinha visto esse arquivo antes. Não creio que você esteja usando múltiplas identidades, então acho que é melhor **remover** esse arquivo.

Comment: mesmo retirando ele, continua não funcionando, eu tinha colocado por indicação de outras pessoas dentro de uma issue do gitlab

Comment: Tem certeza que você subiu o arquivo `id_rsa.pub`? Um erro comum é subir a chave privada no lugar da pública. Se não for isso, então minhas opções se esgotaram, tentaria mudar pro `https` para se comunicar com o repositório adequado e delegaria a opção de mudar pro `ssh` para o **eu** do futuro.

Comment: Infelizmente tenho,vou testar o https. :/